# What is the way of updating my data.frame?

Tags: r

I have some problem updating my data.frame and am at a loss how I might do so. I have a function that updates my data.frame:

```
# Tries to update the data.frame.
updateTable <- function(sample) {
  sampleName = sample[1]
  sex = sample[2]
  dob = sample[3]

  cat("UPDATE ENTRY:
     Current sample: ",sampleName,"
     Sex           : ",sex,"
     Day of Birth  : ",dob," (yyyy-mm-dd)
     ")
  age = getAge(as.Date(dob))
  occurences = which(test_data[,"Name"] == sampleName)
  test_data[occurences,"Age"] <- age
  test_data[occurences,"Sex"] <- sex

  # I tried this, but it returns n number of data.frames in the    test_patients list.
  #return(test_data)

  # And this returns a list with data.frames for each test_patient.
  #test_data[which(sampleName == test_data$Name),] <-c(Name=sampleName, Sex=sex, Age=age)

  # I want to return one data.frame, containing the updated information for each test_patient.

}
```

And a function that calculates the age of a person given his birthdate and the current date:

```
# Calculates the age of a person given his/her birthdate.
getAge <- function(dob)
{
  currentDate = as.Date("2016-12-14")
  lt <- data.frame(dob, currentDate)
  age <- as.numeric(format(lt[,2],format="%Y")) - as.numeric(format(lt[,1],format="%Y"))

  dayOncurrentDateYear <- ifelse(format(lt[,1],format="%m-%d")!="02-29",
                           as.Date(paste(format(lt[,2],format="%Y"),"-",format(lt[,1],format="%m-%d"),sep="")),
                           ifelse(as.numeric(format(currentDate,format="%Y")) %% 400 == 0 | as.numeric(format(currentDate,format="%Y")) %% 100 != 0 & as.numeric(format(currentDate,format="%Y")) %% 4 == 0,
                                  as.Date(paste(format(lt[,2],format="%Y"),"-",format(lt[,1],format="%m-%d"),sep="")),
                                  as.Date(paste(format(lt[,2],format="%Y"),"-","02-28",sep=""))))

  age[which(dayOncurrentDateYear > lt$currentDate)] <- age[which(dayOncurrentDateYear > lt$currentDate)] - 1

  return(age)
}
```

Now input data:

```
test_data <- data.frame(Name=c("Anita", "Bert", "Cornel"), Sex=c(NA), Age=c(NA))
test_patients <- list( c("Anita", 0, "2000-01-01"), c("Bert", 1, "1959-01-01"), c("Cornel", 1, "1960-01-01") )
test_data = lapply(test_patients, updateTable)
```

Now I have some idea's on how to achieve my goal, however I would like to know what is THE way of doing this? I am not very experienced in R and having no books at my disposal I figured why not ask my question here.

1. Would be to expand the lapply with this function as nested function, having a tmp.df for each person
   and then add the transformed tmp.df as a row to test_data before returning the entire data.frame.

Something like (this doesn't work):

```
test_data = lapply(test_patients, function(patient) {
  tmp.df = NULL 
  tmp.df = updateTable(patient)
  rbind.data.frame(test_data[which(sampleName == test_data$Name),], tmp.df)
})
```

2. Set the data.frame from this function by either <<- or with assign("a", "new", envir = .GlobalEnv). (Which is as I saw on other posts here, very ugly.)

So, dear internet. Who can educate me on how I should approach this matter?

Kind regards

## EDIT:

The test_data was a subset of my original, so here is a slightly more extended subset. I'm struggling to connect the answer from [denrou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41162417/3198540) test case to my own data.

```
test_data <- data.frame(Name=c(rep(c("Anita", "Bert", "Cornel"),4)), Sex=c(NA), Age=c(NA), Sample_ID=c(rep(1:12,1)), Time=c(rep(1:4,3)) )
test_data[order(test_data[,"Time"]),]

     Name Sex Age Sample_ID Time
1   Anita  NA  NA         1    1
5    Bert  NA  NA         5    1
9  Cornel  NA  NA         9    1
2    Bert  NA  NA         2    2
6  Cornel  NA  NA         6    2
10  Anita  NA  NA        10    2
3  Cornel  NA  NA         3    3
7   Anita  NA  NA         7    3
11   Bert  NA  NA        11    3
4   Anita  NA  NA         4    4
8    Bert  NA  NA         8    4
12 Cornel  NA  NA        12    4
```

So how can I implement her/his answer when I'm not after creating a new data.frame based on the test_patients vector but want the information from test_patients stored in the test_data data.frame?

Since doing:

```
library(dplyr)
test_patients <- list( c("Anita", 0, "2000-01-01"), c("Bert", 1, "1959-01-01"), c("Cornel", 1, "1960-01-01") )

# This function take a vector and returns a dataframe
to_dataframe <- function(info) data_frame(Name = info[1], Sex = info[2], Birthdate = info[3])

# Now I can turn your patient list into a dataframe
test_data <- lapply(test_patients, to_dataframe) %>% bind_rows()

# And I can calculate the age of a patient with your function
test_data <- test_data %>% 
  mutate(Age = getAge(as.Date(Birthdate))) %>% 
  select(Name, Sex, Age)
```

leads to:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
    Name   Sex   Age
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1  Anita     0     9
2   Bert     1     9
3 Cornel     1     9
```

Please do tell me if I'm not making sense anymore.. I find it difficult to describe these things..

## EDIT2:

For anyone stumbling on this question, looking for an answer;
I can't give you one working with one of the apply-family function's but here's what could help you:

```
for (patient in test_patients) {

  # Set variables.
  sampleName = patient[1]
  sex = patient[2]
  dob = patient[3]
  age = getAge(as.Date(dob))

  # Set reference.
  occurrences = which(test_data$Name == sampleName)

  # Update table.
  test_data[occurrences,"Age"] <- age
  test_data[occurrences,"Sex"] <- sex
}
```

Comment: prefer adding the `drop=TRUE` while subsetting a single column from data.frame

Comment: i.e. `which(test_data[,"Name", drop = TRUE] == sampleName)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! @joel.wilson (However not clear if this would help or just a general tip, since I'm still not getting my desired results.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it :

```
library(dplyr)
test_patients <- list( c("Anita", 0, "2000-01-01"), c("Bert", 1, "1959-01-01"), c("Cornel", 1, "1960-01-01") )

# This function take a vector and returns a dataframe
to_dataframe <- function(info) data_frame(Name = info[1], Sex = info[2], Birthdate = info[3])

# Now I can turn your patient list into a dataframe
test_data <- lapply(test_patients, to_dataframe) %>% bind_rows()

# And I can calculate the age of a patient with your function
test_data <- test_data %>% 
  mutate(Age = getAge(as.Date(Birthdate))) %>% 
  select(Name, Sex, Age)
```

**Edit**

The last command, i.e. `select(Name, Sex, Age)` select the columns which are given in parameter (see `?dplyr::select`). You can perfectly modify this to either select only the column you want or remove it so you keep everything :

```
test_data <- test_data %>% 
  mutate(Age = getAge(as.Date(Birthdate)))
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, it sort of goes in the direction I want it to go.. However, the test_data actually contains a few more columns (such as old sample_names, origin, timepoint etc..) and samples are not unique, since they are measured over time. So when I create a new data.frame per sample (I took the name, sex, and birthdate only because those are the columns I can reference by/or want updated) I'm struggling to merge that with the original. I'll update my question, and hope that provides a better understanding of my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no.. Since this creates a new data frame based on the vector from the test_patient, e.g. the name, sex and date of birth (dob) are converted to a data frame instead of taking account of the other columns from the test_data data frame. And is it just me or is the age staying the same with your code?